# How to write Yup schema in typescript in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik, yup

Actually getting error when defining yup schema:

Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'object')

```
import Yup, { object } from 'yup'
import { useFormik } from 'formik'

interface Account {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const loginSchema: Yup.SchemaOf<Account> = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email().required(),
    username: Yup.string().min(3).max(25).required().matches(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i, "Username should contain alphabets and numbers only"),
    password: Yup.string().required().min(4).matches(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i, "Password should contain alphabets and numbers only")
  })
```

Actually i am new to yup and typescript, so pls tell me the actual way of defining yup in ts

Comment: there is not an item ```{ object }``` in ```yup``` library

Comment: Can you elaborate more what is wrong in my code , it will be great help

Comment: you can check the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code itself except from the import statement.

change

> import Yup, { object } from 'yup'

to

> import * as Yup from "yup";

You are accessing the `object` function through the `Yup`